# How to run xcconfig on buck build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, buck

I include firebase to my pod, inside FirebaseCore.xcconfig there is

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1 FIRCore_VERSION=5.4.1 Firebase_VERSION=5.20.0
```

because above code is never execute, it will always fail to compile since FirVersion.m will always blocks it from compiling.

Wondering if anyone can help me on this? I want to execute above code or FirebaseCore.xcconfig file

Answer (score 1):

You can add these pre-processor definitions as compiler flags using the `-D` option.

[See more information about -D option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)

So in this case you would add extra arguments in your rule e.g.

```
compiler_flags=['-DCOCOAPODS=1', '-DFIRCore_VERSION=5.4.1', '-DFirebase_VERSION=5.20.0']
```

Or something like that